# How to create a Sitecore ribbon button with dropdown menu?

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

The Sitecore PageEditor and Preview interfaces feature a language selector button that triggers a "dropdown"/overlay menu where the user can select a language. How do I replicate this behavior?

(I set out to answer this question, and came up with a solution. Posting to SOF for comment/enhancement.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see how Sitecore does it in the `Sitecore.Client` assembly, `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.ChangeLanguage` and `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.SetLanguage`.

You'll need to create two commands of your own for this. One command is associated with the button, one is executed when a subitem is selected. The example is based on a scenario of changing a country cookie.

**ChangeCountry Command**

First, the command to display the menu. You can see that it displays a `Menu` with dynamic options. Overriding `GetHeader` and `GetIcon` allows the button itself to be dynamic based on the user's current selection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Sitecore.StringExtensions;
using System.Web;

namespace Prototype.Commands
{
    public class ChangeCountry : WebEditCommand
    {
        protected Dictionary<string, CountryOption> _countries = new Dictionary<string, CountryOption>
        {
            {"US", new CountryOption {
                ID = "US",
                Name = "United States",
                Icon = "Flags/32x32/flag_usa.png"
            }},
            {"CA", new CountryOption {
                ID = "CA",
                Name = "Canada",
                Icon = "Flags/32x32/flag_canada.png"
            }},
            {"MX", new CountryOption {
                ID = "MX",
                Name = "Mexico",
                Icon = "Flags/32x32/flag_mexico.png"
            }},
            {"DE", new CountryOption {
                ID = "DE",
                Name = "Germany",
                Icon = "Flags/32x32/flag_germany.png"
            }}
        };

        public override void Execute(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            if (context.Items.Length == 1)
            {
                Item item = context.Items[0];
                SheerResponse.DisableOutput();
                Menu control = new Menu();
                //replace with lookup and loop of available values
                foreach (var key in _countries.Keys)
                {
                    var country = _countries[key];
                    string id = country.ID;
                    string header = country.Name;
                    string icon = country.Icon;
                    string click = "prototype:setcountry(country={0})".FormatWith(key);
                    control.Add(id, header, icon, string.Empty, click, false, string.Empty, MenuItemType.Normal);
                }
                SheerResponse.EnableOutput();
                SheerResponse.ShowPopup("ChangeCountryButton", "below", control);
            }
        }

        public override string GetHeader(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context, string header)
        {
            HttpCookie country = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["country"];
            if (country != null && _countries.ContainsKey(country.Value))
            {
                return _countries[country.Value].Name;
            }
            return base.GetHeader(context, header);
        }

        public override string GetIcon(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context, string icon)
        {
            HttpCookie country = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["country"];
            if (country != null && _countries.ContainsKey(country.Value))
            {
                return _countries[country.Value].Icon;
            }
            return base.GetIcon(context, icon);
        }

        protected class CountryOption
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Icon { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In either Commands.config or an include file, register the new command.

```
<command name="prototype:changecountry" type="Prototype.Commands.ChangeCountry,Prototype" />
```

**Change Country Button**

Create a new Chunk and Button under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Experience`. This ribbon strip is referenced/replicated in Preview mode as well. The button will use the following properties:

[image: Ribbon Button]

The Click field must match the name of your command, and the ID field must match the element ID provided in the `SheerResponse.ShowPopup` call above.

**SetCountry Command**

Next is the command that will be called when an item in your menu/dropdown is selected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands;
using System.Net;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using System.Web;

namespace Prototype.Commands
{
    public class SetCountry : WebEditCommand
    {
        public override void Execute(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            var country = context.Parameters["country"];
            Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(country, "Country not found");
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("country", country);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            WebEditCommand.Reload(WebEditCommand.GetUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

In our example, we're setting a cookie based on the selected value and reloading the page. The value passed in is based on the click event associated with the menu item in `ChangeCountry`. Likewise, the name of the command when configured needs to match what was used in the `ChangeCountry` click event.

```
<command name="prototype:setcountry" type="Prototype.Commands.SetCountry,Prototype" />
```